# Wordpress Menu - creating a fake link

Tags: menus

I like to create Web site mockups for clients using Wordpress. Typically I will only create the landing page and a believable navigation menu. To keep from creating extraneous pages I will create a Custom Link using "#" and then enter whatever menu name. The problem I run into is when I mouse-over the menu link I get a straight cursor symbol instead of the typical mouse-over hand symbol.

Basically I am looking for a simple solution, if it exists, so that when a client mouses-over one of these menu links the cursor changes to the hand so it 'feels' like a real link.

Comment: This question will be closed due to it not having anything to do with WordPress. Please read the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq before posting, thanks.

Comment: `.menu li {cursor:pointer}` didn’t work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS.

.menu li {
cursor:pointer;
}

Comment: @ Wyck understood. Seems rather restrictive but oh well.